# Create File object from Android content URI

Tags: android

I have a content URI in the form of "content://media/external/images/media/175". I am trying to find the absolute path of the image in question in order to send the file in a request. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't convert content URIs to file URIs (a content URI does not necessarily mean you have access to the underlying file). What exactly do you mean by 'in order to send the file in a request'? Include the code you want to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to find the absolute path of the image

A `Uri` is not a file. You cannot convert arbitrary `Uri` values to some filesystem path that you can access. Those `Uri` values might point to:

- A file on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html)
- A file on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) of some other app
- A file that has not yet been downloaded, but will be downloaded on the fly by the `ContentProvider`
- A file that has been encrypted and will be decrypted on the fly by the `ContentProvider`
- A `BLOB` in a database
- Content that will be generated dynamically, the way this Web page is
- And so on

> in order to send the file in a request

[Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) to get an `InputStream` to use in your request. If whatever API you are using does not support an `InputStream`, either:

- [Switch to a better API](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/08/07/for-android-apis-think-streams-not-files.html), or
- Use that `InputStream` to make a local file copy on your own internal storage, then use that file